# ServiceStack root/default.cshtml downloading webpage / not displaying

Tags: c#, iis, servicestack

Currently works 100% fine for me and another designers machine. A different designer is facing this issue:

metadata displays, services display, static content displays. When navigating to the root / (aka default.cshtml) page, the content downloads as a file, rather than rendering.

Currently this behavior is intermittent. Re-Pulling the repository will sometimes fix the issue for this designer for a minute, but the issue will return after an indeterminate amount of time. Example, we ran Gulp, which I'm making assumptions wouldn't impact this, and suddenly the default page starts downloading and won't display again.

I'm assuming this has to do with their machine/setup, but I need some hints as to where to look/debug this.

**Solution**:
Thanks @mythz That was extremely helpful, and led me to the solution!

Issue was node_modules folder being too long and Razor looking at it for Views because it was scanning every folder for views. I did this the following to stop it from looking at Angular's node_modules.

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    `ScanSkipPaths = { "Angular/node_modules/" },
});
```

This stopped Razor from looking at node_modules folder.

**Follow up**:
Is there a way to skip all node_modules folders globally, just in case the path changes in the future?

Comment: Is the Content-Type for the http-response correctly set to `text/html`

Comment: @jHilscher yeah, these were set correctly, ended up being an issue with node_modules folder being scanned for views. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [?debug=requestinfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info) when your AppHost is in [DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#debugmode):

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    DebugMode = true 
});
```

You'll want to look to see if there's any `startUpErrors` listed in the RequestInfo page.

If the issue is due to invalid Razor Configuration, try upgrading to the latest v4.0.62 of ServiceStack and [ServiceStackVS](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS) just released which has [improved support for Razor Intellisense](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.62.md#improved-razor-intellisense).

Configuring [Debug Logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging) and putting a breakpoint on:

```
public override void OnStartupException(Exception ex)
{
    base.OnStartupException(ex);
}
```

May also help identify any issues.

Comment: this led me to solution, I posted details in original post :)

Comment: @Thrashmandicoot ServiceStack already skips the common case of immediate [node_modules/ sub folder by default](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/7c4dbe93048e4e8131a06c5aef06d07a6a97de7c/src/ServiceStack/HostConfig.cs#L122) but `ScanSkipPaths` only lets you specify which immediate directories to skip, not string patterns matching sub directories which is why `Angular/node_modules/` didn't match `node_modules/`.